# symbol lookup error occurs when trying to run an application using memcached

Tags: php, memcached

I have an application with some memcached operations. I have installed php memcached extension version 2.0.1. from configure to make install everything went smoothly, no errors.

Now in my application I instantiate a memcached instance and When I run methods like addServer or get or set, everything runs fine. But when I fire `getStats` or `getVersion` I get this error

`/usr/local/bin/php: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/memcached.so: undefined symbol: zend_parse_parameters_none`

Can anyone help me with this? Been stuck with this since entire yesterday.

Another strange observation is with NetBeans. I use version 7.0.1. When I create a memcache object I get the autocomplete when type in `$memcObj->` but the same is not true when the object is of memcached. No autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `zend_parse_parameters_none` was introduced for the Zend API in 2008.

```
sh ~> git blame Zend/zend_API.h
...
11e5d2f2 (Zeev Suraski        2001-07-30 02:07:52 +0000 247)    _zend_get_parameters_array_ex(param_count, argument_array TSRMLS_CC)
cc2b17d5 (Felipe Pena         2008-03-10 22:02:41 +0000 248) #define zend_parse_parameters_none()                                                                               \
cc2b17d5 (Felipe Pena         2008-03-10 22:02:41 +0000 249)    zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "")
58f88057 (Andrei Zmievski     2001-07-09 18:51:29 +0000 250)
```

I imagine your version of PHP is not compatible with PECL's [Memcached](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached) extension, as your extensions directory has a  timestamp before [2006-11-02](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history) (`no-debug-non-zts-20060613`).

Ideally you would want to look into upgrading PHP. Else, try PECL's [Memcache](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache) extension; which, does offer a stable version to match your PHP build.